# Can Remote server run local server using Php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am in a problem where i want to auto insert some values because of it is not quite to insert them manually. For this I am looking for a mechanism which could fetch the values and insert them automatically. But for this I need to run a local server. I don't want to force Non Technical person to run server manually. So is it possible that server php script can run local server.

Comment: It's difficult to get a handle on what you're actually describing.  But it sounds like you should break the problem into smaller problems.  1) Run a command from PHP code.  2) Write a PHP page which executes that code and renders some meaningful response (probably in JSON).  3) Use jQuery to make an AJAX call to that page.  4) Handle the response in the jQuery code.

Comment: also explain obstacles you have...  agree with @David, can't really figure out question the way it's written

Comment: actually 
1) First There is an HTML PAGE on which we have a link
2) when the user click on it .. Either the jquery , javascript or php handle this click
3) on that click there should be execute a cmd command which run a server. 
4) after getting a response the server starts run. a separate php file should run. That's what i want to know how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if i understand your question correctly. I would use PHP instead of JS.

If you want to execute a PHP script on a remote sever by loading a PHP script on a local server and recieve the result as a var in the local PHP script you could use cURL: http://www.php.net/manual/de/curl.examples.php

If you just want to redirect from a local PHP script to a remote PHP script you can use the header function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

Example: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

If you want to execute terminal commands with PHP to e.g. start a server use exec or shell_exec function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

My suggestion:

Create a PHP script on the remote server, which starts the server with exec() and returns true or false.
On the local server create a PHP script, which loads the remote PHP script with cURL and grabs the return value true or false. After this show an alert message with JS if server start was sucessfull or not.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: See Guys First take my question as a part . I want to run a cmd command using jquery or javascript or through php. First suggest me if there anysolution for it ??

Comment: Just edited my answer. Maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want to call a server-side application within your javascript code. 
indeed you can achieve this following a lot of tutorials on the net (go on google and search for 'php javascript jquery').

Consider you have a page called PhpServerScript.php on your server and the url to reach your php-script is: 
    http://www.myhost.net/PhpServerScript.php

on the other side you have a html page (index.html) with javascript and jquery loaded. 
In order to request data from PhpServerScript.php inside index.html:

```
<script>
    //parameters you want to send to the PhpServerScript.php page
    // if none replace through:
    // var data = {}; 
    var data = {name1: value1, name2: value2};

    $.post('http://www.myhost.net/PhpServerScript.php',
     data,
     function(resultFromServer) { //callback method for processing the result
       //do your job e.g. to display the content in an alert panel
       alert(resultFromServer);
      }
     );
</script>
```

Comment: No No Actually The Php file should be run over my paid server godaddy. but before it run over there first of all the seprate server file should run on the system.

Comment: Please take my question in part . First suggest me about how to run cmd command on a click over html page.

Comment: You cannot achieve this using commando, since you are dealing with event inside the browser. The simplest way is to use javascript